# Cannot find random gems after upgrading to Mac OS X High Sierra (with Docker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler, macos-high-sierra

I have a **Rails 4.2.8** application using **Bundler 1.14.6** running on a **Docker** container.

I recently updated my Mac to OS X **High Sierra**.
Since then, whenever I try to run the server or specs inside the docker container, I get error messages stating that a gem wasn't found in any of the sources. For example:

`Could not find unf-0.1.4 in any of the sources`

The stated gem is actually installed but when I run `bundle install` again it is presented as being installed once again.

When I remove that gem from my dependencies, the same thing happens with another different gem.

I suspect that this might be an issue with **docker** since when I run everything locally it all goes smooth.
I tried to upgrade it to the last available version (**17.10.0-ce**) but the same thing keeps occurring...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this issue is actually related to the [docker-machine-nfs](https://github.com/adlogix/docker-machine-nfs) plugin, which is currently not working properly on Mac OS X High Sierra: https://github.com/adlogix/docker-machine-nfs/issues/79

Basically, the issue is that the file sync under High Sierra isn't working due file system changes.

Upgrading to High Sierra **10.13.2 Beta** fixed the issue!